# Showing nearest feature side to side in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity

I have 2 polygons and I would like to know which side of these polygons is the nearest from each other, probably by pointing out through a new created shapefiles from the analysis.

Is there any tools possible for that in ArcGIS Desktop?

This is the visual representation:

[image: this is the visual representation]

Comment: Have you tried any of the Proximity tools under the Analysis toolbox?  `Generate Near Table` would be a good starting point.

Comment: i already tried the tools, but its not generating new features. i want it to be showed by new generated features like in 'buffer' perhaps

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a single tool that will give you the output you are looking for.  You could write a Python script to achieve this though.  At a high level, a possible workflow would be to:

- `Buffer` your input polygons by a search tolerance
- Iterate through each buffer, performing an `Intersect` against the other buffered polygons
- Append all the results together into a single feature class.

**Input Polygons**
[image]

**First two polygons buffered**
[image]

**Intersect area between the two buffers identified.  FeatureIDs of both polygons can be extracted.**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, i think this the most possible and logical way to get this thing done!